# Using two kv files in one program error

Tags: python-3.x, oop, kivy, python-3.4, kivy-language

I am quite new to OOP, and I am currently trying to create my first project using kivy. The program is currently stuck at the point of when I login I try and open a new kv file, but it will not open. Here is the python code:

```
window_widget = Builder.load_file("LiveScoringV104KVLoggedIn.kv")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def checkLogin(self, username, password):
        usernamesFile = open("dataUsernamesV104.txt", "r")
        passwordsFile = open("dataPasswordsV104.txt", "r")
        for line in usernamesFile.readlines():
            for lineb in passwordsFile.readlines():
                with open("dataprintedUsernameV104.txt", "w") as printedUsername:
                    printedUsername.write(username + "\n")
                if line == username and lineb == password:
                    print("This is working")
                    return window_widget
                else:
                    print("All wrong")
root_widget = Builder.load_file("LiveScoringV104KV.kv")

class StartupHome(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StartupHome().run()
```

when I login, which is correct because this is working is printed, window_widget is not called as it does not run the kv file, yet root_widget is called .How can I get the kv file to run like root_widget? (If you need the kv code just ask)

Comment: is this a minimal example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your example is filled with irrelevant stuff. Make a minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, very new to the site. I've narrowed down to the code in which I need help with

Comment: Your error is not clear. What do you expect to happen that is not happening? None of your code does anything with window_widget, and your line that just says `window_widget` does nothing.

Comment: Ok, I expect window_widget to be called like root_widget is called, but it isn't